# typeScript написать дженерик для функции

Tags: javascript, typescript

У меня есть такая функция

```
type NestedArrayElement = number | number[] | any;

export function func(arr: NestedArrayElement): number[] {
  ... какой-то код
  return numberArr;

}
```

в эту функцию передается массив, внутри которого еще массив или еще два массива, или три массива

```
const arr = [
[0, 1],
[3,4]
]
or 
const arr = [
[[2,3],[5,6],[[7],[7,8]]]
]
```

я попытался написать тип для этой функции, у меня не получилось без any

```
type NestedArrayElement = number | number[] | any;
```

здесь вроде можно написать дженерик, чтобы потом этот тип передавать, может кто помочь?

Comment: Что насчёт четырёх массивов и больше?

Comment: [Возможно, это то, что вы спрашиваете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476762/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-typescript/1476790#1476790) - только вместо number указать number[], если вы ожидаете массивы массивов

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас будет даже 100 массивов внутри, все будет работать также:

```
 export type NestedArray<T> = Array<T> | Array<NestedArray<T>>;
    export const flattenArray = <T>(arr: NestedArray<T>): Array<T> => {
      if (!Array.isArray(arr)) return arr ? [arr] : [];
    
      return arr.reduce<Array<T>>((acc: Array<T>, item: NestedArray<T>) => {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
          return [...acc, ...flattenArray(item)];
        }
        return [...acc, item];
      }, []);
    };

    const arr: NestedArray<number> = [
      [
        [2, 3],
        [5, 6],
        [[7], [7, 8]],
      ],
    ];
```

Ответ взят тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68349501/19366149

Comment: Зачем в типе number? Отдельно числа, как элемента массива, нет

Comment: @SwaD, потому что number внутри

Answer (score 0):

Что насчёт этого?

```typescript
type NestedArray<T> = Array<T | NestedArray<T>>;

export function func<T = number>(arr: NestedArray<T>): T[] {
  ... какой-то код
  return numberArr;
}
```